# Check if you can go back when using react-router MemoryRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6 (ie. with `useNavigate`, and no `useHistory` available).

My app is all setup inside a MemoryRouter like this:

```
     <MemoryRouter >
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Popup />} />
                <Route path="/user/:userid" element={<UserProfilePage />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterForm />} />
                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginSection />} />
                <Route path="/reset-password" element={<ResetPasswordForm />} />
              </Routes>
    </MemoryRouter>
```

I'm trying to create a "Go back" button that takes you back to where you were previously. This is what the button looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BackButton() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const canGoBack = ???

    return (
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)} disabled={!canGoBack}>
            Go Back
        </button>
    );
}
```

The navigate(-1) works fine and takes you back to the previous back. However, I'm trying to figure out how to derive `canGoBack`? I'd like the button to be disabled if there's nowhere to go back.

Comment: You can use `useLocation` `key` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useLocation` to determine whether can go back or not. It has a property called `key` which has two values one is `default` means you can't go back obviously you come from outside the app or new tab and another one is `unique` key of that location that means you are routed inside the app.

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BackButton() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const canGoBack = location.key === 'default';

    return (
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)} disabled={canGoBack}>
            Go Back
        </button>
    );
}
```